# C++ Cant do Loan Calculator: calculation and compiler issue

Tags: c++, calculator

My code is poor, would appreciate help as to what I'm doing wrong and what i should do instead.

My assignment is supposed to be as follows: 
Input:

1. Loan (principal amount).
2. Annual Interest.
3. Amount of years.

Output (incremental per month):
 1. Loan amount. 
 2. Amount paid. 
 3. Monthly Interest.

I figured out how to construct an incremental calculator that can calculate per month the loan, IF monthly payment is given. I tried to create code where monthly payment is calculated, yet I've failed.

Compiler error on line 32 with the pow function.

Monthly Payment= principalAmount * MonthlyInterest / (1-(1/1+MonthlyInterest)^years*12)) (if anyone has a better calculation, please tell, though this is what I was given).

What should I fix/what should I do. Would very much appreciate help.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cmath>
 using namespace std; 
 int main()
 {          
 cout << "Loan calculator"<<endl;   
 double principalAmount, 
 monthlyRate,
 nMonths;
{
    cout<<"Loan amount:"<<endl; 
    cin >>principalAmount;

    cout <<"Annual Interest rate:"<<endl;
    cin >>monthlyRate;

    cout<<"Duration of years:"<<endl;
    cin >>nMonths;      
}

float totalPaid=0;
float monthlyPayment=0;
float remaining=principalAmount;
float interestAdd;
float toAdd;

cout <<"Loan Amount per month, Monthly paid, Montly Interest."<<endl;

while (remaining > 0){
    monthlyRate/=100/12;
    monthlyPayment= (principalAmount * monthlyRate) / (1-(1/(pow((1+monthlyRate),(nMonths)))));
    monthlyPayment++;
    remaining+=interestAdd;

if (remaining > monthlyPayment) {
toAdd=monthlyPayment; }
else {
toAdd=remaining;
}
cout << monthlyRate << ". $" <<interestAdd << ". $" <<toAdd <<". $" <<remaining <<endl;
totalPaid+=toAdd;
remaining-=toAdd;

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `100/12` is equivalent to `8`. Are you sure?

Comment: Where did I do this? 
monthlyRate/=100/12; ?

Comment: Why did you add one to `monthlyPayment` after caucluating the formula?

Comment: I'm trying to do incremental calculations, if you're referring to monthlyPayment++.

Comment: I suggest you should stop using confusing variable names: `annualRate` and `nYears` should be better than `monthlyRate` and `nMonths`, according to what is printed.

Comment: I want the output to be a loop of months, so should i use those variables and divide them by /12

Answer (score 1):

`pow()` takes two parameters, but your code is passing a single parameter to it. This is the reason for your compiler error.

See the `pow()` function's manual page/documentation for more information.

Comment: Okay. So my equation up top: 
Monthly Payment= principalAmount * MonthlyInterest / (1-(1/1+MonthlyInterest)^years*12))

Should be like: 
(pow(nMonths))

Comment: No, you're still passing a single parameter to the pow() function. The pow() function takes two parameters, as I stated. pow(x,y) calculates x raised to yth power.

Comment: Also using `pow` token just after `)` token here is not good and some operator has to be between them.

Comment: Oh duh, yeah I know what you mean. 
pow(nMonths, 12)

Comment: @DragonflyBeach Are you sure?

Comment: I am not. 
The equation requires ^years*12. 
My function is nMonths so years is already in 12.
I need to take: pow((1+MonthlyRate),nMonths)